# Javascript return all indexes of highest values in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the indexes of '**all**' the highest values in an array:

```
[0,1,4,3,4]
```

Need to get back `[2,4]` as a result.

Update: Thanks everyone for the quick responses. After reading some of the earlier comments, it spawned this path for me:

```
var array = [0,1,4,3,4];
var indexes = [];
var highest = Math.max(...array);

array.forEach(function(element, i) {
    if (element == highest) {
        indexes.push(i);
    }
});
```

I know it's a bit verbose, but it makes sense to me. I better read up on '**reduce**'.

Comment: Your efforts so far ?

Comment: I've used this, but I only get back one value out of it: arr.indexOf(Math.max(...arr));

Comment: Why should it renders [2, 4] when the two biggest numbers are 3 and 4 ?

Comment: @KévinHuang this are index numbers for the two 4's in the array

Comment: Oh thanks my bad there !

Comment: The highest value in the array are 2 elements which is the number 4. I having trouble trying to get the indexes of those two elements.

Comment: So, @oprogfrogo, if you can find the highest value, what should your next step be?

Comment: `Math.max()` and `.filter()`.

Comment: @Brad `.filter()` would return the values, not the indexes.

Comment: check the answer bro it might help you bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Math.max` you can get the maximum element. Post that you map over the array and get the indices of this max element. The complexity of this approach is **O(n)**;

```js
const arr = [0,1,4,3,4];
const max = Math.max(...arr);
const res = [];
arr.forEach((item, index) => item === max ? res.push(index): null);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here idea is

- First find the max value using math.max
- Now loop through the array and add the index if the value is same as `max`

```js
let arr = [0,1,4,3,4]
let max = Math.max(...arr)

let op = []
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
 if(arr[i] === max){
    op.push(i)
  }
}
console.log(op)
```

One alternate way of doing is using reduce and a variable to keep track of max value and than access the `max` key's value

```js
let arr = [0,1,4,3,4]
let max = null

let op = arr.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
   op[inp] = op[inp] || []
   op[inp].push(index)
   if(inp > max){
    max = inp
   }
   return op
},{})
console.log(op[max])
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the max value with `reduce` first, then find the indexes:

```js
var arr = [0,1,4,3,4];

var max = arr.reduce((acc,curr) => curr > acc ? curr : acc);
var res = arr.reduce((acc,curr,idx) => curr === max ? [...acc, idx] : acc, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: it fails for arr = [-5]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple version.  Once you have the maximum value, iterate over the list testing each one for a match, adding it's index if it's equal:

```js
const allMax = (xs, max = Math.max(...xs)) => 
  xs.reduce((all, x, i) => x == max ? [...all, i] : all, [])

console.log(allMax([0, 1, 4, 3, 4]))
```

You could fix this up to run in a single pass (skipping the `Math.max` call) but the code would be more complex.

### Update

This is that second version I mentioned:

```js
const allMax = (xs) => xs.reduce(
  (a, x, i) => x > xs[a[0]] ? [i] : x < xs[a[0]] ? [...a] : [...a, i],
  [0]                                
)

console.log(allMax([0, 1, 4, 3, 4]))
```

This does everything in one pass.  It will return `[0]` if you supply an empty list, which might be a problem, but it's hard to know what to do with it.  One advantage is that it will work on other sorts of input. `allMax(['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'd']) //=> [2, 4]`.  Dates should also work or anything you can compare with `<`.

And it's not as complex as I imagined.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly verbose solution that only iterates once. The idea is that you keep track of the highest value you've seen and compare against it.

```
let arr = [0,1,4,3,4];
let maxValue = arr[0];
let maxIndexes = [];

arr.forEach((val, index) => {
  if(maxValue === val){
    maxIndexes.push(index);
  }

  if(maxValue < val){
    maxValue = val;
    maxIndexes = [index];
  }
})

console.log(maxIndexes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Find the max value

```
var max_val = Math.max.apply(null, array)
```

Then use reduce function

```
var max_val_indexes = arr.reduce(function(arr, ele, i) {
    if(ele === max_val)
        arr.push(i);
    return arr;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Looping through using map
2. Capturing max index value
3. Filtering out max index values

```js
var arr = [0,1,4,3,4]

const maxIndex = arr
  .map((v, i, self) => v === Math.max(...self) ? i : -1)
  .filter(index => index !== -1);

console.log(maxIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to find the max value and then loop *again* through the array. You can just keep track of the current max value as you traverse the array *once*:

```js
let arr =  [0,1,4,3,4]

let maxIndexes = arr.reduce((maxes, n, i, a) => {
    let cur = a[maxes[0]]  // current max value
    if (cur == undefined || n > cur) return [i]
    return (cur == n) ? maxes.concat(i) : maxes
}, [])


console.log(maxIndexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get two array one if the duplicate maxim and another is the indexof the maxim number. please check the below code it might help you bro

```js
let a = [1,3,6,6]
Math.max.apply( Math, a );
let index =[];
let y=0;
let maxValue = a.reduce( function (value,obj){
  if(Math.max.apply( Math, a) == obj){
     index.push(y);
     value.push(obj);
  }
  ++y;
  return value;
},[]);

console.log(maxValue);
console.log(index);
```